# Mapper's toForm method does nothing on submit?

Tags: lift

I have a very simple snippet to add a new row to the books table in the database:

```
def add = Book.toForm(Full("Add"), { _.save })
```

Calling this snippet in my template generates a form just fine, and submitting the form gives me a post request, but nothing happens, it never tries to talk to the database, no errors or exceptions occur:

```
09:03:53.631 [865021464@qtp-2111575312-18] INFO  net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers - Service request (POST) /books/ returned 200, took 531 Milliseconds
```

I am not sure if my model's save method is just not being called, or if the save method is not working.  Based on examples in the book "Lift in Action", I am under the impression that the default Mapper save method should just work, and that is what I am using right now.  My model class is simply:

```
class Book extends LongKeyedMapper[Book] with IdPK {
    def getSingleton = Book
    object name extends MappedString(this, 100)
}

object Book extends Book with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Book] {
    override def dbTableName = "books"
}
```

Am I missing something in my model, or does this appear to be correct?  If this should work, how do I debug it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms don't work if you don't have a session (so you need cookies enabled).  The session maps the form name to a function on the server.  Unfortunately, lift doesn't log an error when the form's handler function isn't found.